# How to solve postback in custom sever controls?

Tags: asp.net

I am creating custom server controls.I created a textbox in this used this control in my page.But when page is posted back(postback) the value of textbox gets omitted..I thought of using viewstate  here but m nt getting textbox value .May be m using in wrong way help me plz

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Reflection;
namespace DNWebComponent {
    [DefaultProperty("Text")]
    [ToolboxData("<{0}:DNTextBox runat=server></{0}:DNTextBox>")]
    public class DNTextBox : WebControl, IDNComponent {


        public String _ConnectedField;
        private string _label;
        private TextBox _txtBox;
        private string _connectedField;
        private string _MultiSeekField;
        private string _InputTable;
        public string ControlClientID;

        public DNTextBox() {
            _txtBox = new TextBox();

        }
        [PersistToViewState]

        [Bindable(true)]
        [Category("Appearance")]
        [DefaultValue("")]
        [Localizable(true)]
        public string Text {
            get {
                String s = (String)ViewState["Text"];
                return ((s == null) ? "[" + AspTextBox.Text + "]" : s);
            }

            set {
                ViewState["Text"] = value;
            }
        }


        public DNTextBox(string label)
            : this() {
            this._label = label;
        }

        public String Label {
            get { return _label; }
            set { _label = value; }
        }

        public String ConnectedField {
            get { return _connectedField; }
            set { _connectedField = value; }
        }
        public String MultiSeekField {
            get { return _MultiSeekField; }
            set { _MultiSeekField = value; }
        }
        public String InputTable {
            get { return _InputTable; }
            set { _InputTable = value; }
        }

        public TextBox AspTextBox {
            get { return _txtBox; }
            set { _txtBox = value; }
        }

        public string DivCss { get; set; }

        protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter output) {
            output.Write("<div class=\"" + DivCss + "\" >");
            output.Write(Text);
            output.Write(_label + ": ");
            _txtBox.RenderControl(output);

            output.Write("</div>");
        }

        public bool FillControl() {
            return false;
        }
        protected override void LoadViewState(object savedState) {
            base.LoadViewState(savedState);
            PropertyInfo[] properties = GetType().GetProperties();
            foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties) {
                object[] attributes = property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(PersistToViewState), true);
                if (attributes.Length > 0) {
                    if (ViewState[property.Name] != null)
                        property.SetValue(this, ViewState[property.Name], null);
                }

            }
        }

        protected override object SaveViewState() {
            ViewState["Text"] = AspTextBox.Text;
            //PropertyInfo[] properties = GetType().GetProperties();
            //foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties) {
            //    object[] attributes = property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(PersistToViewState), true);
            //    if (attributes.Length > 0)
            //        ViewState[property.Name] = property.GetValue(this, null);
            //}

            return base.SaveViewState();
        }


        [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
        public class PersistToViewState : Attribute {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it could be of some help if you post your code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is another way to achieve what you are trying to do that will handle all the events and viewstate information:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Reflection;
namespace DNWebComponent {
    [DefaultProperty("Text")]
    [ToolboxData("<{0}:DNTextBox runat=server></{0}:DNTextBox>")]
    public class DNTextBox : WebControl, IDNComponent {


        public String _ConnectedField;
        private string _label;
        private TextBox _txtBox;
        private string _connectedField;
        private string _MultiSeekField;
        private string _InputTable;
        public string ControlClientID;

        public DNTextBox() {
            _txtBox = new TextBox();

        }

        [Bindable(true)]
        [Category("Appearance")]
        [DefaultValue("")]
        [Localizable(true)]
        public string Text {
            get {
                String s = (String)ViewState["Text"];
                return ((s == null) ? "[" + AspTextBox.Text + "]" : s);
            }

            set {
                ViewState["Text"] = value;
            }
        }


        public DNTextBox(string label)
            : this() {
            this._label = label;
        }

        public String Label {
            get { return _label; }
            set { _label = value; }
        }

        public String ConnectedField {
            get { return _connectedField; }
            set { _connectedField = value; }
        }
        public String MultiSeekField {
            get { return _MultiSeekField; }
            set { _MultiSeekField = value; }
        }
        public String InputTable {
            get { return _InputTable; }
            set { _InputTable = value; }
        }

        public TextBox AspTextBox {
            get { return _txtBox; }
            set { _txtBox = value; }
        }

        public string DivCss { get; set; }

        protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e) {
            var div = new Panel{ CssClass = DivCss };

            div.Controls.Add(new Literal{ Text = Text });
            div.Controls.Add(new Literal{ Text = _label + ":" });
            div.Controls.Add(_txtBox);

            Controls.Add(div);
        }

        public bool FillControl() {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: no control is being redered on the page..M getting nothing on running..If u can help me to maintain viewstate...then Plz help..Iam facing the same problem for checkboxlist

Comment: did you try using the control tree instead of rendering every thing? asp.net already have managed all this...

Comment: Actually i dnt knw much abt control tree can u xplain......?Do i hv to make any change in above code to make it run

Comment: @ivowiblo-Hello if i am using two dropdown server control on one page...When i fire one control other is fired automatically....can u help on this

Comment: what do you mean "fired"? It may help creating a new question with some code samples.

Comment: by flired i mean whenever itry to open one dropdown other is automatically opened.....

Comment: so you click in the dropdown and another one is being open? That's weird. Do you have some custom javascript code working on that page?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you have not added the child text box control to your control - because the text-box is not part of control tree, it will not retain its value (or other properties).

You should derive from CompositeControl (or develop UserControl) instead. For example,

```
...
public class DNTextBox : CompositeControl, IDNComponent {

 private TextBox _txtBox;

 protected override void CreateChildControls()
 {
    _txtBox = new TextBox();
    _txtBox.ID = "T";
    this.Controls.Add(_textBox);
 }

 public TextBox AspTextBox 
 {
    get { EnsureChildControls(); return _txtBox; }
 }

 protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter output) 
 {
    output.Write("<div class=\"" + DivCss + "\" >");
    output.Write(Text);
    output.Write(_label + ": ");

    base.RenderContents(output); // this will create html for child controls

    output.Write("</div>");
 }
}
```

*Disclaimer: illustrative code, not tested*

Whenever, you need to refer to the text-box, make sure that you call `EnsureChildControls` as shown in AspTextBox property.

Comment: Its still the same...no value retained

Comment: @mona, please post the new code. Also, try removing `LoadViewState` and `SaveViewState` methods.

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me.I added a method add attribute

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

namespace DNWebComponent {
    [DefaultProperty("Text")]
    [ToolboxData("<{0}:DNTextBox runat=server></{0}:DNTextBox>")]
    public class DNTextBox : TextBox, IDNComponent {
        public String _ConnectedField;
        private string _label;
        private TextBox _txtBox;
        private string _connectedField;
        private string _MultiSeekField;
        private string _InputTable;
        public string ControlClientID;

        public DNTextBox() {
            _txtBox = this;

        }

        public DNTextBox(string label)
            : this() {
            this._label = label;
        }

        public String Label {
            get { return _label; }
            set { _label = value; }
        }

        public String ConnectedField {
            get { return _connectedField; }
            set { _connectedField = value; }
        }
        public String MultiSeekField {
            get { return _MultiSeekField; }
            set { _MultiSeekField = value; }
        }
        public String InputTable {
            get { return _InputTable; }
            set { _InputTable = value; }
        }


        public TextBox AspTextBox {
            get { return this; }
            set { _txtBox = value; }
        }

         public string DivCss { get; set; }

        [System.Security.Permissions.PermissionSet(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand,
        Name = "FullTrust")]
        protected override void AddAttributesToRender(HtmlTextWriter writer) {
            writer.AddAttribute("Label", Label);
            writer.AddAttribute("Text", Text);
            base.AddAttributesToRender(writer);
        }

        protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter output) {
            output.Write("<div class=\"" + DivCss + "\" >");
            output.Write(_label + ": ");

            output.Write("</div>");

        }

        public bool FillControl() {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @VinayC My Problem solved.I got a new problem now m also creating a server control for checkboxlist but getting same problem...checked values don't persist...not getting solved....can u help

Comment: Use the Control tree instead of rendering all the html by hand. Add the controls to the Controls collection in the Init event. It's the only way you won't have nightmares. Trust me.